# Use polars' read_excel method to read data in xlsx format, a ComputeError was reported

Tags: python, python-polars

the code is simple:

```
df_pl = pl.read_excel("./data/data-0806.xlsx")
```

then raise ComputeError:

```
ComputeError: Could not parse `liaozl` as dtype `i64` at column 'cust_no' (column number 93).
The current offset in the file is 5603524 bytes.

You might want to try:
- increasing `infer_schema_length` (e.g. `infer_schema_length=10000`),
- specifying correct dtype with the `dtypes` argument
- setting `ignore_errors` to `True`,
- adding `liaozl` to the `null_values` list.
```

Comment: The error is saying you have the string `liazol` in your `cust_no` column which has been identified as an `int` column. What do you want to happen in this case? You can pass the suggested options via `read_csv_options`: `.read_excel(..., read_csv_options={'ignore_errors': True})`

Comment: Well, ignoring the errors will "convert" `liaozl` to `null` - so it depends on what exactly you want to do in this situation? Do you instead want the column to be typed as `str` and all values kept?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_pl = pl.read_excel("./data/data-0806.xlsx", read_csv_options={"infer_schema_length": 10000})
```

try using the `infer_schema_length`

referred the syntax from here : [Polars read_excel issue with a date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644459/polars-read-excel-issue-with-a-date-format?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

I try these, and sucseed. First, I delete polars folder, re-install polars. Then polars can read_excel small size excel again. But 23000 rows excel failed. Next, I insert read_option:

```
df = pl.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet,
 read_options={"infer_schema_length": 30000})

DeprecationWarning: `the argument read_csv_options` for
 `read_excel` is deprecated. 
It has been renamed to `read_options`.
```